# Decrypt SSL no client certificate in Wireshark Tutorial

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, wireshark, client-certificates

I'm right now at this tutorial [wiki.wireshark.org](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#Complete_SSL_decryption_walk_through)
Everything went fine first, i could start the server with openssl
[image: Server in the Browser]

Afterwards I wanted to send a SSL message with this code in my bash shell.

```
printf 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' | openssl s_client -ign_eof
```

in the output i had the problem with no client certificate or just a self signed certificate. 
[image: Bash Part 1]

[image: Bash Part 2]

Would be great if you had a hint for me, I've been trying for hours.

Comment: The server has an untrusted self-signed certificate, and doesn't trust any CAs so it didn't send any in the `CertificateRequest message`. Off topic.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: ok didn't recognize that. Thanks a lot anyway.